# fitting multivariate curve_fit in python

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit a simple function to two arrays of independent data in python. I understand that I need to bunch the data for my independent variables into one array, but something still seems to be wrong with the way I'm passing variables when I try to do the fit. (There are a couple previous posts related to this one, but they haven't been much help.)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def fitFunc(x_3d, a, b, c, d):
    return a + b*x_3d[0,:] + c*x_3d[1,:] + d*x_3d[0,:]*x_3d[1,:]

x_3d = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

p0 = [5.11, 3.9, 5.3, 2]

fitParams, fitCovariances = curve_fit(fitFunc, x_3d[:2,:], x_3d[2,:], p0)
print ' fit coefficients:\n', fitParams
```

The error I get reads,

```
raise TypeError('Improper input: N=%s must not exceed M=%s' % (n, m)) 
TypeError: Improper input: N=4 must not exceed M=3
```

What is `M` the length of? Is `N` the length of `p0`? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

N and M are defined in [the help](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) for the function. N is the number of data points and M is the number of parameters. Your error therefore basically means you need at least as many data points as you have parameters, which makes perfect sense.

This code works for me:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def fitFunc(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a + b*x[0] + c*x[1] + d*x[0]*x[1]

x_3d = np.array([[1,2,3,4,6],[4,5,6,7,8]])

p0 = [5.11, 3.9, 5.3, 2]

fitParams, fitCovariances = curve_fit(fitFunc, x_3d, x_3d[1,:], p0)
print ' fit coefficients:\n', fitParams
```

I have included more data. I have also changed `fitFunc` to be written in a form that scans as only being a function of a single x - the fitter will handle calling this for all the data points. The code as you posted also referenced `x_3d[2,:]`, which was causing an error.

Comment: Thanks a lot! (I think M is the number of data points, and N is the number of parameters.)

Comment: The help clearly states "ydata : N-length sequence" and "p0 : None, scalar, or M-length sequence", so N is the number of data points and M is the number of parameters. It seems like the error message has them backwards, though :-). If you think this answer was helpful, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: @VolodimirKopey I don't really see what that reply adds to this one - they seem very similar to me.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon it seems that M and N have switched since you last posted a comment.  Now ydata has length M and p0 can be a length-N sequence.

Comment: @Joshua Yup, I submitted the [bug report and the fix](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3172). I suppose I should have updated this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The default `curve_fit` method needs you to have fewer parameters for the fitted function `fitFunc` than data points. I had the same problem fitting a function that took 15 parameters in total and I had only 13 data points. The solution is to use another method (e.g. `dogbox` or `trf`).