# Scipy curve_fit multiple series of data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to have a curve fit that takes into account multiple series of y based on same values of x and same (exponential) law. The y values among the series vary a little since they're experimental but are still close (at same x).

I tried to build two arrays: one with the x and one with the two different series of y

```
def f(x,a,b,c):
    return a*numpy.exp(-b*x)+c
xdata=numpy.array([data['x'],data['x']])
ydata = numpy.array([data['y1'], data['y2']])
popt, pcov=curve_fit(f,xdata,ydata)
```

But this error appears:

```
TypeError: Improper input: N=3 must not exceed M=2
```

Does anyone know how solve this error or a proper way to do this kind of curve fitting?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769340/fitting-multivariate-curve-fit-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should [`concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) the data properly instead of creating a multi-dimensional array. There is nothing in [`curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) that states that the data has to be sorted by `x`:

```
xdata = np.concatenate((data['x'], data['x']))
ydata = np.concatenate((data['y1'], data['y2']))
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata)
```

This assumes that the referenced elements of `data` are all 1D.

Comment: Thanks! I was just too used to Matlab curve fitting tool